# Show that the class of a nilpotent group cannot be bounded by a function of the derived length

Tags: group-theory

> If $G$ is a nilpotent group with positive class $c$, its derived length is at most $[\mathrm{log}_2c]+1$.

This statement can be proved by the inclusion of groups in the derived series and central series.

But I don't know how to prove

> The class of a nilpotent group cannot be bounded by a function of the derived length.

I think I should find a sequence of nilpotent groups for which the derived lengths are equal, but the classes are not bounded. But I have no idea.

Thanks very much.

Comment: HINT: there are metabelian groups of arbitrarily large nilpotency class.

Comment: FURTHER HINT: Restrict attention to p-groups.

Comment: FURTHER FURTHER HINT: ... and restrict further to $p=2$.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: the dihedral groups of order $2^n$ for any $n$! Thanks for the hints~

Comment: @Steve D: the dihedral groups of order $2^n$ for any $n$! Thanks for the hint~

Comment: @ShinyaSakai: So, how about posting it with a proof as an answer? Then you can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Community wiki summary of the answer to remove it from unanswered questions.)

The dihedral group $G$ of order $2^{n+1}$ has a cyclic subgroup $N$ of order $2^n$.  Being index 2, this subgroup is normal, and the quotient, being order 2 is abelian.  Hence the derived length of $G$ is 2; $G$ is metabelian.

The lower central series of $G$ is $$G > N^2 > N^4 > \dots > N^{2^{n-1}} > N^{2^n} = 1$$ so the nilpotency class of $G$ is $n$.

Explicitly: $$G =\langle t, x : t^2 = x^{2^n} = 1, xt = tx^{-1} \rangle \qquad N =\langle x \rangle$$ and $$[x^{2^k},t] = x^{-2^k} x^{-2^k} = x^{-2^{k+1}} \qquad [N^{2^k},G]=N^{2^{k+1}}$$

Comment: I am sorry, I should have done all this by myself. I didn't see Arturo Magidin's last comment and I thought it was a little bit strange to answer my own question. Thank you very much.